# While testing the login flow of Google Plus, my account seems to get invalidated

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus-signin

We're currently building the login flow of our game to allow login with Google Plus, to retrieve an access token that stores their profile data on our backend.  Unfortunately, and it's happened to two of my email addresses now, after logging in, and logging out, uninstalling the app from my phone and/or clearing all the data from it, and removing the app from my `G+` profile, to hammer the flow, my account no longer seems to be able to log in.  I get the login spinny view, and it will just hang there, in logcat spewing out,

```
05-19 15:03:35.644: V/AuthAccountOperation(23492): access token request successful
05-19 15:03:35.674: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:17652>, callingPkg: com.google.android.gms, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games.firstparty]
05-19 15:03:35.676: I/Auth.Core(1415): [TokenCache] Missing snowballing token: no granted scopes set.
05-19 15:03:36.046: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:17652>, callingPkg: com.sixminute.freeracing.test, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games]
05-19 15:03:36.053: I/Auth.Core(1415): [TokenCache] Missing snowballing token: no granted scopes set.
05-19 15:03:36.064: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] getTokenFromGoogle [account: <ELLIDED:17652>, callingPkg: com.sixminute.freeracing.test, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games
05-19 15:03:36.467: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] getAuthtoken(<ELLIDED:17652>, oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games) -> status: null)
05-19 15:03:36.467: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] Extracting token using key: Auth
05-19 15:03:36.485: V/GLSActivity(1415): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
05-19 15:03:36.583: V/AuthAccountOperation(23492): offline access is not requested; requesting access token
05-19 15:03:36.614: I/GLSUser(1415): [GLSUser] getTokenFromCache: [account: <ELLIDED:17652>, callingPkg: com.sixminute.freeracing.test, service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login]
05-19 15:03:36.619: I/Auth.Core(1415): [TokenCache] Missing snowballing token: no granted scopes set.
05-19 15:03:36.630: V/AuthAccountOperation(23492): access token request successful
```

If I leave things be for an hour or so, I'm not sure, at some stage it'll go back to being ok again.  But I test this flow again?  Broken again.

This is making it *extremely* difficult to develop, and any help on how to fix would be extremely appreciated.